# Переместить блок на передний план

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, никак не могу поставить выскакивающий блок на передний план, что только не пробовал уже, ничего не помогает, фото приложил, окно что скрывается за блоками, надо вывести на передний план

```
<div class="s2-item-wrap spoiler-wrap disabled">
 <a href="#q" class="s2-item spoiler-head">
 <span class="img-wrap">
  <img src="img/icons/section_2/1.png" alt="Alt">
 </span>
 <span class="s2-item-text">IT, компьютеры, связь</span>
 <div class="spoiler-body">
В данном разделе собрана полезная информация о компьютерной сфере. Во-
первых, здесь представлены крупные тендеры из области IT по разработке и 
управлению информационными системами. Во-вторых, в этом разделе найдётся 
целый ряд тендеров на поставку готового оборудования – компьютеров, 
оргтехники, комплектующих. В-третьих, здесь есть проекты по ремонту и 
обслуживанию современной вычислительной и офисной техники.
 </div>
 </a>
 </div>
```

js--->

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.spoiler-head').click(function(){
   $(this).parents('.spoiler-wrap').toggleClass("active").find('.spoiler-
 body').slideToggle();
 })
})
```

CSS---->

```
.spoiler-wrap
  margin: 0 0 8px

.spoiler-head
  cursor: pointer
  padding: 5px

.spoiler-body
  margin-left: -130%
  padding: 10px
  background-color: #333
  color: #fff
  border: 1px solid #F39F18
  width: 500px

.spoiler-wrap
  &.disabled .spoiler-body
    display: none
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: я уже что только не пробовал, не помогает

Comment: создайте работающий пример

Comment: http://playcode.io/64959?tabs=console&app.html&style.css&script.js&output
Тут только sass не читает

Comment: создайте работающий пример, демонстрирующий проблему, которую Вы пытаетесь решить

Comment: http://test.asvpages.ru/t1/

Comment: получается перенести блок на передний план ?

Comment: @АлексейСоколов, у вас 15 строчек sass и вы не смогли их преобразовать в css? Если уж просите помочь, то приложите хотя бы немного усилий. Данный ресурс предполагает взаимную помощь, от вас требуется лишь хорошо сформулированный вопрос с примером кода прямо в теле вопроса, что бы он никак не зависел от обстоятельств связанных с работоспособностью внешних ресурсов.

Comment: спасибо, уже нашел выход из ситуации

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте стили

```
.s2-item-wrap.active {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```